# Active/Dynamic choice parameters - fill with particular job names

Tags: jenkins, groovy

How to achieve that choice parameter is filled with job names which starts/contains "mdc" string using groovy script?

I tried with Active Choices Parameters plugin and with Dynamic choice parameters plugin:

```
import jenkins.model.*
import hudson.model.*

def matchedJobs = Jenkins.instance.items.findAll { job ->
job.name =~ /mdc_.*/
}

matchedJobs.each { job ->
return job.name
}
```

but i only get something like:

```
hudson.model.FreeStyleProject@77973801[mdc_Create_Branches] 
hudson.model.FreeStyleProject@775b1202[mdc_deploy]
hudson.maven.MavenModuleSet@4734119f[mdc_R_18.1]
hudson.maven.MavenModuleSet@23c8f32d[mdc_trunk]
```

in drop down box.

It should be only (without that extra job type and brackets):

```
mdc_Create_Branches
mdc_deploy
mdc_R_18.1
mdc_trunk
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove **matchedJobs.each{..}** and use collect method:

```
def matchedJobs = Jenkins.instance.items.findAll { job ->
job.name =~ /mdc_.*/
}.collect{ it.name }
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work:ERROR: Build step failed with exception
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: job for class: Script1
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:53)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoGetPropertySite.getProperty(PogoGetPropertySite.java:52)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGroovyObjectGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:307)
 at Script1$_run_closure2.doCall(Script1.groovy:7)

Answer (score 0):

Ok i've found solution:

```
def matchedJobs = Jenkins.instance.items.findAll { it ->
it.name =~ /mdc_.*/
}.collect { it.name }
```

It should be "it" instead of unknown property "job".

Thanks!!!